# Aligning divs with flexbox. 2 divs full width and 2 divs inline at half of width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout of 2 divs of full width and 2 divs of half width (the last 2 divs should be in one line).

The HTML is like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box--full">1</div>
    <div class="box--full">2</div>
    <div class="box--half">3</div>
    <div class="box--half">4</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

[class*="box--"] {
    display: flex;
    margin: .25rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    color: white;
}

.box--full {
    background: red;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.box--half {    
    background: blue;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

I'm wondering why the 2 last divs doesn't have a half of available width and why aren't they in one line. I would like to avoid adding a wrapper for the last 2 divs.

I found that adding `flex: 0 1 50%` applies the desired width to the last 2 divs but they still are not inline.

Is it possible to make them inline without making an additional wrapper?

Here's the link to codepen: http://codepen.io/sunpietro/pen/Mepmam

Answer (score 9):

They are not in the same line, because they do have `margin`, and `margins` take a little space, so you have to decrease percentage:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

[class*="box--"] {
    display: flex;
    margin: .25rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    color: white;
}

.box--full {
    background: red;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.box--half {    
    background: blue;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box--full">1</div>
    <div class="box--full">2</div>
    <div class="box--half">3</div>
    <div class="box--half">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of `.25rem` margin on each `.box`, so what you can do is use `calc(50% - .50rem)` which is equal to `50% - margin on both sides of box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
[class*="box--"] {
  display: flex;
  margin: .25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  color: white;
}
.box--full {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.box--half {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 1 calc(50% - .50rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box--full">1</div>
  <div class="box--full">2</div>
  <div class="box--half">3</div>
  <div class="box--half">4</div>
</div>
```

Note: `box-sizing: border-box` keeps the padding and border inside width of element, but not the margin.

Also if you want `box--half` to stay `50%` and not stretch to full width you can use `flex: 0 0 calc(50% - .50rem)`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
[class*="box--"] {
  display: flex;
  margin: .25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  color: white;
}
.box--full {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.box--half {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - .50rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box--full">1</div>
  <div class="box--full">2</div>
  <div class="box--half">3</div>
  <div class="box--half">4</div>
  <div class="box--half">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box full">1</div>
<div class="box full">2</div>
<div class="box half">3</div>
<div class="box half">4</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    margin: .25rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    color: white;
}

.full {
    background: red;
    flex: 2 100%;
}

.half {    
    background: blue;
    flex: 1;
}
```

It works, and also using two classes make your code look clearer